# Why does Romans 5:19 say "many" instead of "all"? (Overview)

Tags: life-of-jesus, sin, romans, adam, original-guilt

> By one man’s disobedience many were made sinners
>
> Rom 5:19

Why does it not say "all" but "many"? Because the previous verse says:

> By the offence of one judgment came upon all men to condemnation
>
> Rom. 5:18

Does this mean that not all were made sinners though upon all came to condemnation?

I am interested in an overview of the major views in Christianity.

Comment: The is a question on hermeneutics on this https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20614/what-sort-of-phrasing-is-the-many-in-romans-5  but it is pretty technical

Comment: @emma questions like this on _this_ site require a Faith Tradition (Catholic, Baptist, Lutheran, etc...) to give a Christian answer from a doctrinal standpoint.  On the other site, you'll get a technical answer from a neutral viewpoint. I don't think it would be a bad thing for someone to re-answer the other question in a non-technical way.  I'll ask on their site what to do in this case.  But here the question should remain closed unless you want to edit it to add a doctrinal perspective so concrete (useful to you) answers can be provided.

Comment: why can't i receive or hear what all faith traditions say, so that i can learn and if need be make up my mind, which if any i want to subscribe to, instead of cancelling my question?

Comment: @emma you can certainly ask for an overview of approaches to the question.

Comment: @MattGutting who do i ask? what is the procedure?

Comment: @MattGutting otherwise please edit my question to make it acceptable. thanks.

Comment: Emma, you can [edit] the question yourself - perhaps the last paragraph - to state fast you're interested in an overview of the major views in Christianity.

Comment: @MattGutting i followed your advice, i think, and nothing.

Comment: @emma Patience. I and one other have voted to reopen the question. These things take a bit of time and a consensus of users. It's not at all a bad question, now that you've edited it.

Comment: @MattGutting thanks. am i allowed to vote to re-open it too? if yes, how do i do that?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought this was a good question and have voted it up, even though it may have been answered in Hermenutics.  Problem, as I see it (being a new contributor to Christianity Stack) is I didn't even know there was a section called Hermenutics, and some people probably don't even know how to pronounce Hermenutics, let alone know what it means!  So can we please have this question re-opened in Christianity Stack?

Comment: Emma is a new participant - let's be NICE and encourage her rather than make it so difficult to post questions.